# Deserializing a dynamic returns Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue does not contain a definition for 'info'

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have RESTful endpoint that returns the following:

```
{"error_msg": "{'status': 1, 'info': \"Operation is not allowed on 'XXX, ['YYY']'\", 'key': 'ZZZZ', 'extra': 'None', 'data': {}, 'EEEE': False}"}
```

Some text was replaced above (XXX, ZZZ etc.).

My code is as follows:

```
dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
Console.Error.WriteLine(response.error_msg.info);
```

After building running the code I get the following error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'info'

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like the input to the api is not proper..

Answer (score 5):

That's because `error_msg` here is a string, not an object. Either make it *not a string*, or deserialize twice, i.e. get the `string error_msg` out, and then *deserialize that string*.